# Sort multidimensional array alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I sort a array like this alphabetically:

```
$allowed = array(
  'pre'    => array(),
  'code'   => array(),
  'a'      => array(
                'href'  => array(),
                'title' => array()
              ),
  'strong' => array(),
  'em'     => array(),
);

// sort($allowed); ?
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order multidimensional array recursively at each level in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501340/order-multidimensional-array-recursively-at-each-level-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aha! You need `uksort();`

[Comparison of PHP sorting functions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) (dam useful)

**Edit:** Reason is, you seem to want to sort inside arrays as well? AFAIK ksort by itself doesn't do that - it outright ignores the value of the original array.

**Edit2:** This ought to work (though uses recursion instead of kusort):

```
function ksort_deep(&$array){
    ksort($array);
    foreach($array as &$value)
        if(is_array($value))
            ksort_deep($value);
}

// example of use:
ksort_deep($allowed);

// see it in action
echo '<pre>'.print_r($allowed,true).'</pre>';
```

**Important:** As a side effect of not using `uksort()` if the same array references to itself, you get an infinite loop. This won't happen in normal cases, but you never know :)

Comment: What parts? I'm not using keys, I'm just sorting the value.

Comment: firstly, what does 'is_array()' do?

Answer (score 4):

[`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) ?

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
ksort($allowed);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 2):

```
bool ksort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). The 'See Also' section is usually very helpful