# sorting multi dimensional array alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
[0] => Array (
    [term] => punk
    [term_html] => <a href=""> punk </a>
    )
[1] => Array (
    [term] => conflict
    [term_html] => <a href=""> conflict </a>
    )
[2] => Array (
    [term] => Crass
    [term_html] => <a href=""> Crass </a>
    )
[3] => Array (
    [term] => bct 2
    [term_html] => <a href="">
    )
```

How can I sort this array alphabetically based on 'term' of the array inside array?

i tried this:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $search_terms_html[term];
}

uasort($search_terms_html, 'sortByOrder');
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort multidimensional array alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526600/sort-multidimensional-array-alphabetically)

Comment: uksort(); .......

Comment: just tested with uksort() ... same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison callback function passed to `uasort()` is expected to return a value < 0, 0, or > 0, describing the relationship between its arguments. In your example, the callback is simply returning the the unchanging value `$search_terms_html[term]`; you are not using the arguments representing the array elements (and passed as parameters to the callback function, `sortByOrder()`).  Assuming that the 'term' elements are strings, try defining the callback as:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a['term'],$b['term']);
}
```

`strcmp()` returns values of a sting comparison consistent with the callback's expectations.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way I find out to sort an entire multidimensional array by one element of it:**

```
<?php 
$multiArray = Array( 
    Array("id" => 1, "name" => "Defg"), 
    Array("id" => 2, "name" => "Abcd"), 
    Array("id" => 3, "name" => "Bcde"), 
    Array("id" => 4, "name" => "Cdef")); 
$tmp = Array(); 
foreach($multiArray as &$ma) 
    $tmp[] = &$ma["name"]; 
array_multisort($tmp, $multiArray); 
foreach($multiArray as &$ma) 
    echo $ma["name"]."<br/>"; 


?>
```

Outputs

- Abcd
- Bcde
- Cdef
- Defg