# sorting a foreach function loop result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, foreach

I have a MySQL query that gets the result of the entire MySQL database into a php array called `$parents`

then I have a foreach function loop that display result from that array

the function:

```
 function subtree($id, $parents) { 
 if (isset($parents[$id]))
 foreach ($parents[$id] as $child) 
 {
 subtree($child, $parents);
 }
 }
```

I need to sort the array result of this function,
or to get the result into a `new_sub_array` then sort it and display result

any way to modify the function to do what i need?

Comment: Sort in the database query..

Comment: i need to sort from array not the query

Comment: yes there are many ways.

Comment: @chx, so where is your idea in how to do the many ways?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order multidimensional array recursively at each level in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501340/order-multidimensional-array-recursively-at-each-level-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition

```
if (is_array($parents[$id]))
```

If Value is array then look for next sub tree

```
else
```

otherwise write value.

If you want to sort an array - just use one of [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) at the beginning of subtree()

### Good idea is to don't use recursion, instead of this you can use iteration and well prepared sql query instead of sorting in PHP ;)

Your function could look like this, I am not sure if I understand you, but it should be ok.

```
function subtree($parents) 
{
    if (is_array($parents))
    {
        sort($parents);
        foreach ($parents as $key => $value) 
        {
            subtree($value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $parents;
    }
}
```

The $id argument is unnecessary.

Comment: can you modify the function ? been trying that with no luck

Comment: the $id is the parent id that i need to get the child of.
the array is like 
parent-LeftChild1,RightChild1
Parent(LeftChild1)-Leftchild2,RightChild2
,,
then the function should print each child of the main parents and childs of childs and so on, i just need to sort the result of the function

Comment: So if you want get child of specific parent id, then put to function as argument something like this $parent[$specific_id]. Did your array looks like this http://pastebin.com/JXdDRL5A ?

Answer (score -1):

You'd sort the values when you call them from the database. So if you sorted them in descending order of date, for example:

`SELECT * FROM values WHERE :id=$id ORDER BY date DESC`

Basically, `ORDER BY` is your friend. [This helped me a lot.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: need to sort from the function and not the query

Comment: Then this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) is definitely what you want to be using. Loads of functions for sorting arrays.

Comment: the problem is that i can't get to find a way to sort it inside the function., the result is always unsorted