# PHP sort endless array and keep the index strings

Tags: php, arrays

I want o sort a multidimensional array (which I don't know the length) and keep the index strings. The data of this multidimensional array is from a directory which can have unlimited folders & files.

I have successfully grabbed the folder structure into an array using this [List all the files and folders in a Directory with PHP recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function/56245224#56245224) and I can sort the array with a recursive function like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501406/3355243.

#### Problem

When sorting, all the array indexs are replaced with numbers. I'd like to keep the array index as strings because it holds the folder name.

#### Input

```
Folder A => Array
(
    file.php,
    file1.php,
    Folder B => Array 
    (
        file.php,
        file1.php, 
        Folder A => Array 
        (
            file.php,
            file1.php, 
        )
        something.php
    ),
    something.php
),
Folder B => Array 
(
    other.php,
    other2.php 
),
Folder C => Array 
(
    Folder A => Array 
    (
        a.php,
        b.php
    ),
    something.php
)
```

#### Expected output

```
Folder A => Array
(
    file.php,
    file1.php,
    something.php,
    Folder B => Array 
    (
        file.php,
        file1.php, 
        something.php,
        Folder A => Array 
        (
            file.php,
            file1.php, 
        )       
    ),  
),
Folder B => Array 
(
    other.php,
    other2.php 
),
Folder C => Array 
(
    something.php
    Folder A => Array 
    (
        a.php,
        b.php
    ),  
)
```

#### Current output

```
0 => Array
(
    file.php,
    file1.php,
    something.php,
    0 => Array 
    (
        file.php,
        file1.php, 
        something.php,
        0 => Array 
        (
            file.php,
            file1.php, 
        )       
    ),  
),
1 => Array 
(
    other.php,
    other2.php 
),
2 => Array 
(
    something.php
    0 => Array 
    (
        a.php,
        b.php
    ),  
)
```

#### Final goal

To show the array / folder structure into a select box with Groups & Options.

[image]

Comment: And your attempt at resolving this failed where?

Comment: @El_Vanja in the recursive function in the link that I posted.

Comment: I understand that the function you're using isn't producing the result you want. I'm asking about your own efforts to try and modify this function or perhaps devising your own function based on the ideas provided in similar topics such as that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

The solution of the link [Order multidimensional array recursively at each level in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501340/order-multidimensional-array-recursively-at-each-level-in-php/4501406#4501406) uses `ksort` to order the array and the solution, in my case, I had to use the `asort`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

> asort — Sort an array and maintain index association